# Jmeter http request sampler not working when it goes idle

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 2.11 for simulate 10000 thread users. I use CSV data set config to simulate 10000 user load and take 2-3 HTTP request in my test plan. All 10000 user load applied successfully by Jmeter but main problem is when my last request goes idle (as I put my Jmeter http request on home page of my website) all sessions goes timed out after some time.
I also configure "app pool's Idle time out=0" and my application's web config's "session state timeout is 20" (I also increase this time from 20 min but no way). Also Keep Alive is checked on all http request.

Please suggest me what to do for keep my last request's session alive.

Comment: What code do you have currently and what have you tried so far in order to check what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter threads are never idle, if thread doesn't have any more samplers to execute or no more loops to iterate it's being shut down. 10 000 users is quite a high load, it might be a problem with your JMeter configuration, i.e. it is not capable of generating and sustaining 10 000 threads. In 99% of cases *jmeter.log* file has enough troubleshooting information.

In the meantime few recommendations:

1. Upgrade to the latest version of JMeter (for the moment it's [Apache JMeter 2.13](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-2.13.zip))
2. Make sure you use 64-bit server JRE or JDK
3. Provide JMeter enough Java Heap space, by default it comes with 512Mb only which is not enough to simulate 10k users
4. Run JMeter test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
5. Disable all Listeners during test run

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for above points explained and few more tips and tricks.

Comment: Thanks for recommandations but I have taken care of all these points. Even then I got problem. I don't getting any troubleshoot information in jmeter.log file.

Comment: Try getting Java threads dump with [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) and update your question with the output.